# Est-ce que le mot "politicien" est considéré comme péjoratif par rapport à "homme politique" ?

Tags: usage

J'ai récemment entendu quelqu'un affirmer que le mot "politicien" aurait une connotation péjorative comparé à "un homme politique".

**Est-ce vrai ? Car en faisant des recherches je n'ai rien trouvé qui *confirme* ou *infirme* ceci.**

Comment: Les politiciens ils sont vraiment très très méchants.

Answer (score 6):

Le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/politicien) qualifie l'adjectif *politicien* de « souvent péjoratif ». Ce n'est pas nouveau (le TLF cite Barrès, 1918).

Le nom *politicien* n'est pas en soi péjoratif — le TLF cite d'ailleurs le même ouvrage de Barrès parlant (non ironiquement) d'un « bon politicien ». Même si le caractère péjoratif de l'adjectif a déteint sur le nom, on peut encore utiliser le nom de façon neutre. Par exemple, en regardant des occurrences récentes dans le journal *Le Monde* :

> [un politicien en pleine descente aux enfers](http://www.lemonde.fr/ameriques/article/2014/05/01/rob-ford-un-politicien-en-pleine-descente-aux-enfers_4410256_3222.html) (nom, neutre)
>   [un jeu politicien](http://www.lemonde.fr/europeennes-2014/article/2014/05/22/sarkozy-demolit-l-ue-existante-tout-en-disant-qu-il-l-aime_4423949_4350146.html) (adjectif, péjoratif)
>   [du jeu politicien](http://www.lemonde.fr/idees/article/2014/05/29/pierre-desproges-ou-l-anti-dieudonne_4428424_3232.html) (adjectif, neutre)
>   [Politicien autocrate, il veut …](http://www.lemonde.fr/sujet/99f4/thabo-mbeki.html) (nom, neutre)

J'ai quand même l'impression que si on inclut non seulement le journal lui-même mais aussi les blogs et commentaires, on trouve plus d'occurrences péjoratives du nom (exemples : « [cessons de prendre des pincettes et d'essayer de recycler, comme un politicien qui sait qu'il doit avoir l'air d'être proche des gens, …](http://yannforestier.blog.lemonde.fr/2014/05/27/surpris-du-vote-fn/) » (blog, légèrement péjoratif), « [C'est à cela que l'on distingue l'homme d'Etat du politicien](http://luipresident.blog.lemonde.fr/2014/05/29/non-francois-hollande-na-pas-tenu-les-trois-quarts-de-ses-engagements/) (commentaire, franchement péjoratif) »). Cela tend à montrer que le nom *politicien* reste formellement neutre mais est de plus en plus péjoratif dans l'usage populaire.

Answer (score 3):

*Politicien* est péjoratif lorsqu'il est accolé à *politique* : la *politique politicienne* en est la pire expression : cela sous-entend que la politique n'est pas au service du peuple, mais au service des politiciens.

Dans l'environnement actuel un *politicien* s'occupe plus de ses intérêts (ou au moins uniquement ceux de son parti) que des intérêts de ceux qui l'ont élu, il manipule les règlements et les média à des fins pas toujours avouables ou en désaccord avec son discours.

Il reste *homme politique* pour parler de quelqu'un qui honore son mandat, ou *homme d'état* pour souligner un engagement et une vision au service de la nation.